# Istikharah decision, can my dreams be used too? Is my sihr affecting me making my decision?

Tags: sihr, istikharah

Bismillah
Assalamualaikum, I hope you can clarify the things that have been bothering me. Here's a little background:

I have a best friend of 5 years. We always had our ups and downs but recently she's changed a lot. We always had arguments and she would say things to intentionally hurt me. She also had another new friend who interfered and told me directly that she could now take my best friend away from me. My best friend chose to be friends with the new person instead of me but she also wants to continue being friends with me but done nothing as her personality has always been like that.

I then found out that someone sent a sihr to me. Not too sure if my now ex-best friend was sent too. I am sad that someone had sihr done and could possibly affected me and my friend to break up.

I want to be friends with her but I am unable to as her friend that "took" her away from me is still in the picture. I have prayed tawbah, hajat and istikharah to gain clarity.

I have dreamed 3 times of me and my friend being nice again to one another. But apart from my dream, in reality, I am still confused and 50/50 on whether I want to put hope being friends with her again or not. My heart would still want it but my mind would be logical and be reminded of the hurtful things she's done to me and the nice things.

I have thought about it psychologically and also listen to my heart and it is contradicting and confusing and the dreams that I had I do not know if it's helping. My sihr has yet to be gone and I also do not know if it's what's affecting me and my friend and creating the 3rd party situation.

How do I go about from here? How do I have my head and my heart not contradict with one another? Is my dreams valid or just sleep play? Both choices, being friends again or moving on are both very difficult, how do I know what is better? If the sihr sent to me affecting my istikharah decisions?

I hope your experience may help give me advices that would be helpful in my situation.